# Increase increment size of keyboard backlight

Tags: keyboard, defaults, backlight

I usually have my keyboard backlight either: all the way up, at the lowest setting or off. It is (slightly) annoying to have to hold down F5/F6 keys, when I never use the middle values.

Is there a way to increase the increment?

Alternatively (perhaps even better), is there a way to get and set the value directly from the terminal or AppleScript?

Comment: I'm not on my Mac right now, so I can't test anything. But you can look into /Users -> your_username -> Library -> Preferences, and open com.apple.bezelservice.plist. You have some brighteness preferences...

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but at my end (on Mavericks) that plist only holds 3 keys (BatteryHistory, afActionHistory, randomData).